# XMLRPC 32300:transport error only on Cron Job

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, xml-rpc

I'm running a few scripts using the XMLRPC function in Wordpress, but I am receiving the error "An error occurred - -32300:transport error - could not open socket" on my scripts.

The funny thing is that when I run the scripts manually, everything works perfectly. When I run it as a cron job, I am receiving e-mails with this error message. The things that I have done with no success are...

1) Disable all plugins
2) Contact my hosting company support. They don't know why and left me with "I'm not a programmer" answer.

All of my other scripts that query various APIs or RSS feeds run just dandy, but anything that is trying to query the XML RPC feed all die from this error. Can anyone help me diagnose the problem? I am running Wordpress 3.5 which comes with XML RPC enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. For the millions of others out there who have the 32300 socket error problem, mine was fixed by removing the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] in my xml rpc path when calling the new IXR_Client. Didn't know I couldn't use the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] like that.